# Is there anything like "tremolo arm" for acoustic guitar?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, sound, vibrato

If an electric guitar have tremolo arm, floyd rose, or bigsby for doing vibrato sound. Is there anything (or tool) that can make vibrato sound in an acoustic guitar. Other than manually pullback the neck.

Thank you.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can do a vibrato with the left hand similar to how unfretted string instrument players do it.  While the vibrato depth is obviously shallower than on unfretted instruments and restricted to single non-open strings, it is still discernible on fretted nylon strings.

Answer (score 4):

There is indeed!

(at 1m46s)

I don't believe they're widely manufactured though, not from what I could find

Answer (score 2):

Some of the Bigsby vibs will do the job.Particularly those designed for semis. They may be kinder to an acoustic guitar because they attach to the part of the guitar where the knob is for the strap, rather than on the belly itself. Watching the above video, it was difficult to tell whether the soundboard was being moved as the arm worked, or whether it was the reflection from the moving guitar, but I guess there will be a fair bit of extra stress at the bridge, that may need to see the inside beefing up. As the Bigsby needs only fittings on the end of the guitar, it could be removed without much evidence being left. Not so with Floyd-Rose type !